# Framework linking error, image not found?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, frameworks, linker

I'm using DarwiinRemote's WiiRemote.framework in my app.

I already fixed some issues by downloading the source code and requiring garbage collection, and building for 10.5. However, when I try to add it to my project, I get the console error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/WiiRemote.framework/Versions/A/WiiRemote
Referenced from: /Users/chasemeadors/Documents/Apps in development/Animation/build/Debug/Animation.app/Contents/MacOS/Animation
Reason: image not found
```

I've done some searching on the internet, but they're all framework specific, and not really making much sense to me. So I was hoping someone on here could give a short, sweet, understandable answer?

Download link for the framework: (*note* my changes i.e. garbage collection not made)
http://sourceforge.net/project/downloading.php?group_id=183966&use_mirror=softlayer&filename=WiiRemoteFramework0.5-src.tar.gz&a=58980345

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The framework is apparently expecting that your app will be copying it into the app bundle's Frameworks folder.  Create a Copy Files build phase, add the framework to it, and set the destination to the Frameworks directory.

Comment: Do i need to add the build phase when building the framework or my application? I highlighted "Frameworks" in the drop down box, then what needs to go in the "path" box. Could you explain a little more how it works?

Comment: The copy phase would go in your application build, and you should leave the path empty (that would create a sub-path under the Frameworks directory, which isn't what you want)

Comment: +1 - I'm new to XCode in general and a similar error was killing my motivation.  Thank you